# von Neumann algebras as C*-algebras with multiplicative conditional expectation $A^{**}\to A$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra. We identify $A$ with its canonical image in the bidual $A^{**}$. Consider the following conditions:

(1) $A$ is a von Neumann algebra.

(2) There is a multiplicative conditional expectation from $A^{**}$ onto $A$, that is, a map $\pi\colon A^{**}\to A$ that is a *-homomorphism and such that $\pi(a)=a$ for all $a\in A$.

Then (1) implies (2): Consider the predual $A_*$ of $A$, and the canonical embedding $\kappa\colon A_*\to (A_*)^{**}$. Then the dual of $\kappa$ has the desired properties.

Note that $A^{**}$ is always a von Neumann algebra.
One can show that (2) implies that $A$ is a monotone complete AW*-algebra.
However, is it also a von Neumann algebra?

> Q1: Does (2) imply (1) ?

Assuming (2), let $J$ denote the kernel of $\pi$. Then $A$ is (*-isomorphic to) the quotient $A^{**}/J$. 
However, a quotient of a von Neumann algebra by a closed, two-sided ideal need not be a von Neumann algebra. (For example, the Calkin algebra is such a quotient and not a von Neumann algebra.)

In the commutative case, we might also consider the following more general question:

> Q2: Is the quotient of a commutative von Neumann algebra by a closed, two-sided ideal again a von Neumann algebra?

Equivalently, is every closed subset of a hyperstonean space again hyperstonean?

Comment: Your proof that $A$ is complete, doesn't it also implies that $\pi$ is normal ? If yes then the Kernel of $\pi$ is weakly closed and I think you are done, isn't ?

Comment: This is not clear to me. To show that $A$ is monotone complete, let $(a_j)_j$ be a norm-bounded increasing net in $A_{sa}$. Then, since $A^{**}$ is monotone complete, there is $b\in A^{**}_{sa}$ that is the supremum: $a_j\leq b$ for all $j$, and $b$ is the smallest element with these properties. Now, since $\pi$ preserves order, we have $a_j=\pi(a_j)\leq\pi(b)$ for all $j$, and thus $b=\pi(b)$. However, if we start with any increasing net in $A^{**}_{sa}$, then I don't see why $\pi(\sup_j a_j) = \sup_j \pi(a_j)$.

Comment: Hum... yes you are right, it is not clear.

Comment: Ok, all I can tell is that your question is equivalent to the following question: if $A$ is a retract of a von Neumman algebra, does $A$ is also a von Neumann algebra ? To which I don't know the answer, but which sound a bit more like something that might have been studied...

Comment: (For my other remarks, I got confused by the fact that when $A$ is a von Neumann algebra then $\pi$ is normal because it is weakly continuous)

Comment: *"is every closed subset of a hyperstonean space again hyperstonean?"* https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378199/stone-%c4%8cech-boundary-is-not-extremally-disconnected

Comment: @HannesThiel Again, apologies for replying to a seven-year-old comment, but $b = \pi(b)$ does not need to be true, even if $A$ is a vNa. For example, let $A = L^\infty([0, 1])$. Pick a character $\phi$ on $A$ which extends evaluation at 0 on $C([0, 1])$. Pick an increasing sequence of continuous functions $(a_n)$ s.t. $a_n(0) = 0$ for all $n$ and $a_n$ converges weakly to 1. $A^{**}$ has a direct summand of $\mathbb{C}$ corresponding to $\phi$. Then $b$, the supremum of $a_n$, evaluates to 0 on that direct summand…

Comment: $\pi(b)$ however, can be proved to be the supremum of $a_n$ by a corrected version of your argument, so $\pi(b) = 1$ in this case, whence $b \neq \pi(b)$.

Comment: @DavidGao Thank you for picking this up (and for your nice answer to Question 1). I see your point that $\pi(b)$ may not agree with $b$. One only has $b \leq \pi(b)$. But it seems to me that $A$ is nevertheless monotone complete, with the supremum in $A$ given by $\pi(b)$. Does that sound OK to you?

Comment: @HannesThiel That seems to be the case. I’m not doubting $A$ has to be monotone complete, just pointing out a minor error in the original argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a seven-year-old question, so I'm not sure if an answer is still meaningful at this point, but no, $A$ needs not be a vNa. There is even a commutative counterexample. In fact, fix any monotone complete commutative $C^*$-algebra $A$ which is not a vNa. Then $A$ is injective in the category of unital commutative $C^*$-algebras and $*$-homomorphisms. (See, for example, https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.2995 .) Hence, the identity map $A \rightarrow A$ can be extended to a multiplicative conditional expectation $\pi: A^{**} \rightarrow A$.

Answer (score 12):

The answer to Q2 is no, and $l^\infty/c_0$ is already a counterexample. Its lattice of projections is $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/fin$, which is not complete.