# Stone-Čech boundary is not extremally disconnected

Tags: gn.general-topology, stone-cech-compactification, separation-axioms

Recall that a topological space is called extremally disconnected if the closure of every open subset is still open. Every discrete space is of course extremally disconnected, and the standard non-trivial examples are the Stone-Čech compactifications $\beta X$ of discrete spaces $X$.

In a paper I have seen now the claim that if $X$ is infinite and discrete, then the Stone-Čech boundary $\partial_\beta X := \beta X \setminus X$ is never extremally disconnected. But I have a hard time figuring out why ... ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can suppose $X=\omega$. Let $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ be a continuum family of infinite subsets of $\omega$ with pairwise finite intersection. Define $Y_i=\bar{X_i}-X_i$. So the $Y_i$ are pairwise disjoint non-empty clopen subsets in $\beta\omega-\omega$.

For $J\subset I$, define $Y_J$ as the closure of $\bigcup_{j\in J}Y_j$. So $Y_J\cap Y_i=\emptyset$ for each $i\notin J$.

If by contradiction $\beta\omega-\omega$ is extremally disconnected, $Y_J$ is clopen for each $J$. These are pairwise distinct, by the previous paragraph. So we obtain $2^c$ distinct clopen subsets in $\beta\omega-\omega$. But there a surjection from $2^\omega$ to the set of clopen subsets of $\beta\omega-\omega$ (namely $Y\mapsto\bar{Y}-Y$), so we get a surjection from $2^\omega$ onto some set in which $2^c$ injects. Contradiction.

---

Added: Here's a possibly more intuitive and explicit answer. Write $A\subset^* B$ to mean $A-B$ is finite. Write $X=\bigsqcup X_n$ with each $X_n$ infinite. Define $Y_n=\bar{X_n}-X_n$. Then $Y_n$ is clopen, so $\bigcup_n Y_n$ is open. I claim that $\bar{Y}$ is not open.

Otherwise, it's clopen, hence has the form $\bar{Z}-Z$ for some subset $Z$ of $X$. Then $Z$ has the following property [which expresses being the sup of $(X_n)$ in the Boolean algebra $2^X/\mathrm{fin}$]: $Y_n\subset^* Z$ is finite, and for every $Z'\subset X$ having the property that $Y_n\subset^* Z'$ for every $n$, we have $Z\subset^* Z'$. But now choose $z_n\in Z\cap Y_n$ and define $Z'=Z-\{z_n:n\in\omega\}$. Then $Y_n\subset^* Z'$ for all $n$, but $Z-Z'$ is infinite, contradiction.

Comment: I don't understand why $Y_J$ is closed. But even if not, this is no problem for the argument: Extremally disconnected spaces have the property that if two open subsets are disjoint, then their closures will be again disjoint. So we have $\overline{Y_J} \cap Y_i = \emptyset$ if $i \notin J$, and hence $2^{\mathcal{c}}$ distinct clopen subsets $\{\overline{Y_J}\}_{J \subset I}$ in the Stone-Čech remainder.

Comment: But why is every clopen subset of the Stone-Čech remainder of the form $\overline{Y} \setminus Y$ for some $Y \subset \omega$?

Comment: $Y_J$ is closed because it's defined as "the closure of..."

Comment: Let $F$ be clopen in $\beta X-X$, and $F'$ its complement. Being disjoint open in $\beta X$, there are disjoint open subsets $U\supset F$, $U'\supset F'$ in $\beta X$. Then $beta X-(U\cup U')$ is closed and discrete, hence finite. So we can enlarge $U$ to assume $U$ and $U'$ to be the complement of each other. It easily follows that $F= \bar{Z}-Z$ with $Z=U\cap X$.

Comment: (*"being disjoint open in $\beta X$"* in my previous comment is a typo: I meant *"being disjoint compact subsets in $\beta X$"*)

Answer (score 1):

For an explicit pair of disjoint open sets with intersecting closures work on the binary tree $2^{<\omega}$ of finite sequences of $0$s and $1$s. For every $x\in2^\omega$ let $A_x=\{x\mathbin{\upharpoonright}n:n\in\omega\}$, the branch that consists of the initial segments of $x$.
Let $Q$ be the (countable) set of $q\in2^\omega$ that are eventually constant, and let $P=2^\omega\setminus Q$ be its complement. Let $U=\bigcup_{q\in Q}A_q^*$ and $V=\bigcup_{p\in P}A_p^*$. ($A^*$ is short for $\operatorname{cl}(A)\setminus A$.)
Then $U$ and $V$ are open and disjoint in the boundary. If their closures were disjoint then there would be a subset $C$ of $2^{<\omega}$ such that $V\subseteq C^*$ and $C^*\cap U=\emptyset$. However, an application of the Baire Category theorem will yield many $q\in Q$ for which $A_q^*\cap C^*\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: I think this example is easier to visualize by identifying the boundary of the tree with the Cantor set $C\subset [0,1]$. Then I am looking for a point $a$ that is in the closure of $(a-\varepsilon,a)$ and $(a,a+\varepsilon)$, e.g. we have an increasing sequence and a decreasing sequence converging to $a$. We can now use the self-similarity and use that $C$ consists of four copies of $C$. Let $f$ be the increasing map mapping $C$ to the second copy of $C$. Then the sequences are given by $f^n(0)$ and $f^n(1)$.

Comment: That will not work: in $\beta\omega\setminus\omega$ disjoint open $F_\sigma$-sets have disjoint closures. The sets you describe are of this nature. The open set $V$ in my example is not an $F_\sigma$-set.

Comment: In fact, one can pretend that the boundary is the Cantor set; the idea of the example is that the sets $P$ and $Q$ are so entwined that the closures of corresponding open sets shoudl intersect. ($P$ and $Q$ are like the sets of irrational and rational numbers respectively.)